# pipenv install throws "Requirement" object has no field "use_pep517"

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv, python-3.11, pipenv-install

- Upgraded python (using pyenv) to 3.11.4
- Upgraded pipenv to 2023.7.23 version.

`pipenv lock` works successfully.
However, `pipenv install` or `pipenv sync -d` throws errors.

```
File "/Users/kkannar/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 651, in _cleanup_procs
    dep.use_pep517 = True
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kkannar/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/common.py", line 18, in __setattr__
    raise ValueError(f'"{self.__class__.__name__}" object has no field "{name}"')
ValueError: "Requirement" object has no field "use_pep517"
```

I have tried setting pyyaml to 6.0.1 or 5.3.1 but does not help.

System details:
Apple M1

Rosetta mode (i386)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Running

```
pipenv sync -v
```

showed more detail on how the error arose sufficient to allow working out the root cause.

In my case my pyproject.toml file was incorrect - the licence field had become detached from the [project] object and was treated as part of the [project.scripts] object.